# Why does my phone charges fast when WiFi is on?

Tags: charging, lenovo, lenovo-a6000-plus

My phone is Lenovo A6000+
Original charger and Stock OS. 
Edit: it is a two months old phone with no other complaints.

Comment: Poor, unclear, and too-short question. -1. Your phone charges faster when Wi-Fi is on, and slower when it is off?

Comment: Sorry. But nothing else to add, as you said, it charges fast when WiFi is on and slower when it is off.

Comment: I removed the downvote, but please [edit] your question, make it longer, and improve the grammar.

Comment: Have you tried using the free apps named "Ampere" or "Trepn"? If so, please [edit] in more information. What did you learn?

Comment: Do you have concrete evidence to show us that your device charges fast when Wi-Fi is on and charges slow when Wi-Fi is turned off? Also, which Android version are you running?

Comment: I haven't used any apps for that. As I said, its a relatively new phone. And I have no evidence other than I know the phone charge twice the speed when WiFi is ON. Lenovo A 6000+ charge very slowly. It may take up to 2 hours for full charge. Turning WiFi ON reduced at least 30% of that time. All I wanted to know was is this a feature or something like that, as there are no defects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I can think of why your charges faster on WIFI, with the information given, is you have data enabled. If data is enabled and WIFI is enabled your phone uses WIFI. However if data is enabled and WIFI disabled, your phone will use data, which on my phone uses 1.5 times more power than WIFI with a good connection. You can disable data by going to Settings>mobile data>off (on some phones it is under the "More..." settings).

Comment: Thx, I think that is the reason as my data is always on...